# lightbox link will not open in popup on my server but opens fine on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery

go to www.bravojewelers.com on top you will see contact then select California. when you click on it it opens a new pge insted of a popup like on me local host

```
           <!--- Contact US ---->
          <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          $('.lightbox').lightbox();
            });
          </script>


           <a class="lightbox" href="http://www.bravojewelers.com        /form/demo.php?lightbox[iframe]=true&amp;lightbox[width]=1050&amp;lightbox[height]=700"><font class="leaf">California&nbsp;(Main)</font>
           </a>
```

what could be the reason  Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Open your browser's console (F12) and look at the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because browser cannot load your `lightbox` script as you can pointed out from the console log of your browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.bravojewelers.com/final/virgin/includes/js/lightbox/jquery.lightbox.min.js
```

which results in another error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'lightbox'
```

Fix the path to your `lightbox` script to make it works, otherwise you can also try this link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.pack.js"></script>
```

Btw, some images of your site are having the same problems as well.

Comment: oh my God it was the Js folder name wrong it would of been js not capital letter.

Comment: i got another issue if you guys can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668862/include-multiple-javascript-window-loader